# How to acquire variables from a text file? In C

Tags: c

How do I store data from another text file as variables?

Im currently using fgetc to read and output the content from another file as you can see in the provided image.

[image]

But how would I get the data to separate and store each into a variable? For example:

- a variable storing “New_York”,
- a double variable storing “40.6638332”,
- and a double variable storing “-73.938484”?

Since I’ll need the floats to not be read as a string, I feel like using fgetc isn’t optimal, but how would I be able to separate these lines of text?

```
cities = fopen("cities.dat", "r"); //Opens cities.dat file for reading

if (NULL == cities) {//Ensures that the file is actually there
    printf("\nInvalid File. :( \n");
}else{
    printf("\nFile Found!\n"); 
}

 do {
    ch = fgetc(cities);
    printf("%c", ch);

} while (ch != EOF); // End of file reached

fclose(cities); //Close cities file after use.
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68302704/read-csv-string-into-vector-c/68303738#68303738

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: You should be able to read the file with an `fscanf()` loop.

Comment: If you're not familiar with the `scanf` family of functions, this isn't the way to learn. Go read a tutorial. You're expected to know the basics when posting questions here.

Comment: If the file is not there, there's no point continuing to execute... And, if it is, don't output the `EOF`...

Comment: Does the data file have spaces between the columns or does it have a tab between the columns?

Comment: `fgets` in combination with `sscanf`.

Comment: The thing you need is support for a csv file, a thing from the 70's and still very very useful and used. It is [documented here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) for example. In `C` `scanf` and family are scanners, hence the name, were written to consume this type of data, tabular line oriented data with fields separated by some terminator. As this thing precedes the internet and the w3c, do not count very much on the RFC.

Comment: post a complete code and a small representative file. Help others help you. Help others with good questions.

Answer (score 1):

With `fgets` and `sscanf`:

1. Read a line from the file as a string (`line`)
2. Parse the values you're interested in with something like `sscanf`
3. Do something with the values (here I'm just printing them back to the console)
4. Repeat for every line

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[256];
    FILE *fp = fopen("./cities.dat", "r");

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file: %s.\n", strerror(errno));

        exit(1);
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
        char city[64];
        double latitude = 0;
        double longitude = 0;

        // memset(city, 0, sizeof(city));
        // not required (see chqrlie's comment below!)

        int result = sscanf(
            line,

            // make sure to not overrun 'city' buffer
            "%63s %lf %lf",

            // it's okay to pass 'city' like this
            // another valid way would be &city[0]
            city,
            &latitude,
            &longitude
        );

        // only touch read variables if everything went smoothly
        if (result != 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to parse line. Offending line: %s", line);

            continue;
        }

        // do something with the parsed values
        // here i'm just printing them back to the console
        printf(
            "I read lat=%f long=%f for city=%s\n",
            latitude,
            longitude,
            city
        );
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

This should give you a starting point on how to read values from a file.

Note that this piece of code cannot read city names that contain whitespace.

If you need more complex processing, you could use more advanced string operations like `strchr`, `strtok` (`strtok_r` is better but I don't think it is standard) etc.

If you wanna go more advanced you can define a struct that represents one entry of your data:

```c
struct datapoint {
    char city[64];
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
};
```

And then work with that type instead of 3 different variables.

Comment: Advice: `memset` is not required, you should remove the redundant `\r` in the messages and print the offending line in case of error. You might also report the cause for `fopen` failure using `strerror(errno)`

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks, incorporated them into my post. (except printing the offending line when parsing failed)

Comment: good. Printing the offending line is a great help to identify a problem in the data file, such as multiple words for the city name. It does not cost much  to write `fprintf(stderr, "Malformatted line encountered: %s\n", line);`

Comment: @chqrlie I agree, but I think it's more readable to omit the `\n` so there aren't two new lines printed. This could go on (I think empty lines can be encountered too) etc.

Comment: if you insist on avoiding the extra newline, even in case `line` does not have one, you could use: `fprintf(stderr, "Malformatted line encountered: %.*s\n", (int)strcspn(line, "\n"), line);`

Comment: @chqrlie neat, didn't know about `%.*s`!

Comment: Learn something new everyday :)