# Table Data Reader Using Delimeters

Tags: c++

I want to convert data structured like a CSV file into a table like below:

"Player, PPG, RPG, APG, BLK \n Tim Duncan, 19.8, 10.8, 3.0, 2.2 \n Kareem Abdul-Jabbar, 24.6, 11.2, 3.6, 2.6"

I want to make a table print out in the terminal like below:
"Player | PPG | RPG | APG | BLK " (1st line of table)
"Tim Duncan | 19.8 | 10.8 | 3.0 | 2.2" (2nd line of table)
"Kareem Abdul-Jabbar | 24.6 | 11.2 | 3.6 | 2.6" (3rd line of table)

But it prints out like this:

"Player | PPG | RPG | APG | BLK " (1st line of table)
"Tim Duncan | 19.8 | 10.8 | 3.0 | 2.2 \n Kareem Abdul-Jabbar | 24.6 | 11.2 | 3.6 | 2.6" (2nd line)

This is the function that I wrote:

```
void display_table (const string& table_data, char delimeter, string new_line_char)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < table_data.length(); k++)
    {
        if (table_data[k] == delimeter)
        {
            k++;
            cout << " | " << table_data[k];
        }
        else if (k == table_data.find(new_line_char)) // Checks to see if index matches the ending
        {
            k++;
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << table_data[k];
        }
    }
}
```

Then I prompt the user to choose the column delimeter and new line delimeter:

```
string user_table_data;
char delimeter;
string new_line_char;

cout << "Type in the data you want to print out: ";
getline(cin, user_table_data, '\n');

cout << "What would you like the delimeter to be between columns of the table?  Type here: ";
cin >> delimeter;
cin.ignore();

cout << "Which character would you like to indicate a new line?  Type here: ";
getline(cin, new_line_char, '\n');
cin.ignore();

display_table(user_table_data, delimeter, new_line_char);
cin.ignore();
cin.get();
```

The function works with the input I stated earlier without user input.  Once I have user input, there are bugs that I cannot locate.  Any help with what is causing my output to not print out the way I expect it?

Comment: I guess that you type in your console literally "\n", and then your `new_line_char` is a backslash followed by n, instead of LF (LineFeed), or ASCII 10. So, then that's what you get in your output.

Comment: Read this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68302704/read-csv-string-into-vector-c/68303738#68303738

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I see where I got an error.I also tried using a semi-colon and having the user input a semi-colon to separate the row of each table like below:

Player, PPG, RPG, APG, BLK; Tim Duncan, 19.8, 10.8, 3.0, 2.2 ; Kareem Abdul-Jabbar, 24.6, 11.2, 3.6, 2.6

It works when I input the delimeter and new_line_char directly, but it does not work when I ask the user.  Any ideas where the error is in the function?

Comment: I found my error.  When I conditioned on k == table_data.find(new_line_char), I only referred to the FIRST instance of that character in the string.  I was not varying the position.  I should have said k == table_data.find(new_line_char, k) so it could start looking after the kth index.

Comment: While that is where the issue lies, I still don't understand what you meant by "works without user input". Moreover, is `new_line_char` meant to be a char? If it is meant to be a char, then you should declare it as one and can just use `table_data[k]==new_line_char`. If it is not meant to be a char, then `new_line_char` is a misnomer. In addition, assuming it is indeed a string, although it may not matter in this particular case, the time complexity of `k==table_data.find(new_line_char,k)` is not good and `table_data.compare(k, new_line_char.size(), new_line_char)==0` should be used instead.

Comment: What I meant by "works without user input" was when I defined a fixed string, my function worked.  It did not work initially when I was taking in user input.  

Thank you for the suggestion.  I am just learning more about C++ and I was not aware of that method.  I am reading a book right now and trying some of the practice problems.  I'll take a look at that method and learn more about it :)